# Oracle UPDATE using SELECT statement that includes JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I'm porting an H2 UPDATE/SELECT statement to Oracle, and am running into a syntax issue that I'm having trouble diagnosing.

I have 3 tables, `Users`, `Cars`, and `Trips`. They look like:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS;
+------------+----+--------+
|  USERNAME  | ID | CAR_ID |
+------------+----+--------+
| John.Smith |  1 |     5  |
| Abby.Smith |  2 |     6  |
+------------+----+--------+

SELECT * FROM CARS;
+----+--------+-------+
| ID |  MAKE  | COLOR |
+----+--------+-------+
|  5 | Subaru | Green |
|  6 | Honda  | Red   |
+----+--------+-------+

SELECT * FROM TRIPS;
+----+------------+---------+
| ID |  USERNAME  | MILEAGE |
+----+------------+---------+
|  8 | Abby.Smith |      87 |
|  9 | John.Smith |      23 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

However, we have now decided to add a new column to `Trips`, and keep track of the car model (only) instead of the user. As an intermediate result, before dropping the `USERNAME` column, I'm trying to achieve:

```
+----+------------+---------+-----------+
| ID |  USERNAME  | MILEAGE | CAR_MODEL |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+
|  8 | Abby.Smith |      87 |     Honda |
|  9 | John.Smith |      23 |    Subaru |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+
```

And my (non-functional) statement looks like:

```
WITH USER_MODELS AS
(SELECT USERNAME, MAKE FROM USERS JOIN CARS ON (USERS.CAR_ID = CARS.ID))
UPDATE TRIPS SET CAR_MODEL =
    SELECT MAKE FROM USER_MODELS
    WHERE TRIPS.USERNAME = USER_MODELS.USERNAME
```

However, the syntax error I receive is:

```
UPDATE TRIPS SET CAR_MODEL =
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

Which is throwing me for a loop. The `SELECT` statement is immediately following the `UPDATE`, which is itself preceded by a `WITH` clause that seems to include a properly-formatted `SELECT`.

Comment: [Oracle doesn't support using a subquery factoring clause in an UPDATE statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10008.htm#i2112182) - [they can only be used with a SELECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2065706).

Comment: Thanks @BobJarvis. What's the usual workaround for this kind of scenario? Oracle is not my strong suit, so "subquery factoring clause" is not a term I would have known to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, but you need to put the WITH clause inside the subquery:

```
UPDATE TRIPS SET CAR_MODEL =
( WITH USER_MODELS AS
       (SELECT USERNAME, MAKE FROM USERS JOIN CARS ON (USERS.CAR_ID = CARS.ID))
  SELECT MAKE FROM USER_MODELS
   WHERE TRIPS.USERNAME = USER_MODELS.USERNAME
);
```

Comment: This works perfectly - thanks Tony. Maintains the "feel" of the original statement as well.